# Google does not find my google site

Tags: google-sites

I have created a website via google site (at the beginning of this year).

Now google does not find it. Neither if I search for relevant key words, nor if I even search for the correct address.

The site can be access without any problems though.

How does this happen?

Comment: Do you have the `no follow, no index` meta tag active?

Comment: Could you post a link to your site?

Answer (score 0):

Is your site shared publicly?  Go to your Site's Sharing and Permissions settings (open the site while logged in, click the gear a the top right and select Manage Site near the bottom of the list. Select Sharing and Permissions at the right) and select the top level of the site listing. Then select the first item in the Who Has Access list and make sure you have selected Public on the Web.